# Service Outage - Import

Tags: google-bigquery

We are having import issues since 8:15 am PST, June 1st. Looks like import is stuck or timing out. I am still seeing problem @ 12:00 pm PST, June 1st.

Data sent is not getting imported and the Web interface shows pending. Jobs are now pending for 3+ hrs.

Are there any known issues at this time?

Comment: We are not Google Support.

Comment: Google watches StackOverflow for google-bigquery tags

Comment: That may be true, but I'm sure its for a means of QC, and improving their product/documentation where many users encounter the same issues. This isn't a forum where Google is going to comment and state that they're working on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We experienced a very large internal customer taking up all of our import resources. We have safeguards in place to make sure external users can't hog all of our capacity, but these controls were missing for internal Google users. We've already put in one mitigation to prevent this from happening in the future and will likely add a couple more.

Imports should be proceeding normally, as of about 1:15 PM PST today. Please ping this thread if you continue to see this issue.

Comment: Thanks!. Our import started working from 12:30 pm PST